# Java-Chars can rotate left but can't rotate to the right?

Tags: java, text, rotation

where: Roteer = Rotate,
Links = Left, Rechts = Right....

it seems that if you input "Oliebol",3 into roteerNaarLinks, the output will be 'bololie', which is supposed to happen. But if you input "Oliebol",1 into roteerNaarRechts, the output will be 'lOliebo' but it should become  'llieboo', how can I fix this? :)

```
public class Roteer {

        public static String roteerNaarLinks(String invoer, int n){
            String in = invoer;
            int aantal = n;

            for(int i = 0; i< aantal; i++){
                char firstLetter = in.charAt(0);
                in = in.substring(1);
                in = in + firstLetter;
            }

            return in;
        }
        public static String roteerNaarRechts(String invoer, int n){
            String in = invoer;
            int aantal = n;

            for(int y = n; y > aantal; y--){
                char lastLetter = in.charAt(in.length()-1);
                in = in.substring(1);
                in = lastLetter + in;
            }

            return in;
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't get that output. For `roteerNaarLinks("Oliebol", 3)` I get `ebolOli` and `roteerNaarRechts("Oliebol", 1)` I get `Oliebol`

Comment: Yes for some reason, the roteerNaarLinks does work, but the roteerNaarRechts doesn't, it should give 'lOliebo'

Comment: Why is there `for(int y = n; y > aantal; y--){` and not just `for(int i = 0; i< aantal; i++){` like in the first method? If you want to do something `x` times, it doesn't matter whether you do something `x` times to the right, to the left or upside down; you can still use the same `for` loop to do it `x` times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` will never execute in `roteerNaarRechts`. You set `aantal = n` and then `y = n` and then you say the loop should execute while `y > aantal` which is never true. Change it to

> for(int y = n; y >= 0; y--)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating the output string character by character I would propose following solution (which still can be tuned, depending on your requirements)

```
public class Roteer {

    public static String roteerNaarLinks(String invoer, int n) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(invoer.length() * 2);
        sb.append(invoer).append(invoer);
        int offset = n % invoer.length();
        return sb.substring(offset, offset + invoer.length());
    }

    public static String roteerNaarRechts(String invoer, int n) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(invoer.length() * 2);
        sb.append(invoer).append(invoer);
        int offset = invoer.length() - n % invoer.length();
        return sb.substring(offset, offset + invoer.length());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String inputString = "Oliebol";
        System.out.println("--- roteerNaarLinks");
        for (int i = 0; i <= inputString.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(roteerNaarLinks(inputString, i));
        }

        System.out.println("--- roteerNaarRechts");
        for (int i = 0; i <= inputString.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(roteerNaarRechts(inputString, i));
        }
    }
}
```